# If Python dictionaries are ordered, why can't I index them?

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, cpython

The question says it all. Python dictionaries are insertion ordered since Python 3.6 (in the CPython implementation). It is a language feature in 3.7. I can even `d.popitem()`. Why can't I index them, i.e. `d[3]`? Or can I?

Comment: What if your dictionary was like this: `d = {3: 'hello', 7: ',', 4: 'world', 8: '!'}`? Would `d[3]` be `'hello'` or `'!'`?

Comment: Good question! I don't know, we would likely need different notation, but theoretically, would it be possible to implement?